# Vertipaq Analyzer Metrix pane in Daxstudio

Tags: daxstudio

How do you close the Vertipaq Analyzer Metrix window in Daxstudio? I want to close it to see the Server Timings window. I do not know any other way than to close the whole Daxstudio. The Auto Hide option makes things worse. Once I use it I am not able to pin it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one of those guys who come over and you won't ask them away. It is not closable but it can be neglected. Do not monkey around with any of the two icons in the upper corner on the right. Just switch the pane for Server Timings or whatever another pane you need using the tabs at the bottom.

[image]